# Movie identification: Virtual reality future, polluted world, human mincer

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a film made in the early 90s (maybe even 80s). Seen it in my childhood:

There was a girl living in a future where everybody basically lives in virtual reality. She accidentally connects to her mom's 'dream' where she sang opera with some sort of a Pavarotti guy. Then she somehow finds herself in a post-apocalyptic world where people live underground and there's some sort of a sacrificial mincer/fan. 
There was also a forbidden polluted zone and some guy pursued the heroine there. Eventually it turns out the cyberworld is run by the girls's dad, who retires and she takes his place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're referring to the 1992 film "[Mind Warp](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100152/)" (AKA [Brain Slasher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindwarp_%28film%29)), a film so bad it's actually making my keyboard melt.

The main character lives with her mother in a post-apocalyptic world. As you can see from the video below, there's a sequence where she invades her mother's VR (opera) fantasy.

> In 2037, after a nuclear disaster has just about destroyed the Earth,
>   the planet's remaining dwellers retreat to Inworld, an enclosed
>   biosphere where computers control all aspects of life. But a beautiful
>   young woman rebels against the Inworld's pre-fabricated existence and
>   demands the right to experience "real" life. So the biosphere's System
>   Operator exiles Judy to the mutant-ridden outside world. Once there,
>   she is kidnapped by deformed cannibals who want her to breed with
>   their evil leader. Will Judy be able to escape the horrors of this
>   futuristic, toxic wasteland?

Comment: +1 for the video. Although I was unable to watch it till the end still made me laugh hard during learning for exams.

Comment: Richard, thank you!
Anyway, I've just recollected one part of my childhood... I guess it'll rewatch it anyway